# Outlook 1908/build 11929: Modern Authentication/MFA/App Password behavior

Tags: microsoft-outlook, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm onboarding our clients onto Modern Authentication and am trying to document the behavior of Outlook desktop (2016/365 click-to-run) with regards to MFA and/or App Passwords.

The Modern Authentication login was triggered on a test user/test machine with a new install, and the Microsoft Authenticator was used along with the M365 credentials.  Now I can't seem to unauthenticate: deleted all credentials from Credentials Manager, clicked Sign Out from Outlook, rebooted, to no avail.

Question 1: how to do you actually force a re-authentication with Outlook desktop?

I had assumed we could then use App Passwords to prevent Outlook challenges on the desktop side, but I can't even get that back as an option.

Question 2: Are App Passwords still the recommended means of authentication with Outlook desktop?

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1: 
It is suggested to try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile to force a re-authentication with Outlook.

For Question 2:
This can be used according to your personal needs. If you often log in to your email account on different devices or in different environments, it is recommended for you to use this feature for the safety of your email account.